# Excel SUMIF statement inside IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

I would like to create a SUMIF statement inside another statement. My data is below. I would like to create a SUM of time for 'Person A', but only if  'Type 2'. So for my formula is =SUMIF(B$1:B$5,"A",A$1:A5)

"Time .    Person .   Type

1:10 . A . 1

0:21 . B . 1

0:45 . A . 2

3:45 . C . 1

1:54 . A . 2"

Comment: So use SUMIFS(), where you can add as many criteria as you need, ie both person and type...

Comment: How would that look like to stack SUMIF statements?

Comment: Something Like This `=SUMIFS(A1:A5,B1:B5,B1,C1:C5,C5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A5,B1:B5,"A",C1:C5,2)
```

Comment: You can replace the "A" with any other text, or the "2" to any number and it should still work. If you edit the table this should update automagically, check data->update if it doesn't